# Sql Order by on multiple column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I've the below result

```
VendorName | IncidentID | IncidentStatus | IncidentDate
-------------------------------------------------------
XYZ        | 100        |     Open       | 02-JUN-2011    
XYZ        | 101        |     Open       | 03-JUN-2011  
ABC        | 102        |     Open       | 01-JUN-2011  
XYZ        | 103        |     Open       | 01-APR-2011  
ABC        | 105        |     Open       | 05-JUN-2011
```

I want to order `VendorName` which has latest incident. Vendor `ABC` has the latest incident hence it should come first with all other incident for same vendor and then next Vendor with all respective incident in descending order.The desired result is like this -

```
VendorName | IncidentID | IncidentStatus | IncidentDate  
-------------------------------------------------------
ABC        | 105        |     Open       | 05-JUN-2011 
ABC        | 102        |     Open       | 01-JUN-2011
XYZ        | 101        |     Open       | 03-JUN-2011 
XYZ        | 100        |     Open       | 02-JUN-2011    
XYZ        | 103        |     Open       | 01-APR-2011
```

`ORDER BY IncidentDate desc, VendorName` doesn't give the desired output.  Any help ?

Comment: Can you post the entire query/table structure? Your `ORDER BY` clause looks like it should work...

Comment: Can you comment further on the ordering of vendors? See the issues raised in response to my answer

Comment: @David - Vendor which has latest incident should come on top, It's ok for me to have second vendor with same incident date (in case tie up) down in order.

Comment: So you'd break the tie using the vendor name?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT 
        VendorName, 
        IncidentID, 
        IncidentStatus, 
        IncidentDate, 
        MAX(IncidentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY VendorName) maxDate
    FROM yourTable
) t
ORDER BY t.maxDate DESC, t.VendorName ASC, t.IncidentDate DESC
```

Refer to: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm

Answer (score 4):

This will do it ...

```
ORDER BY MAX(INCIDENTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY VENDORNAME) DESC, INCIDENTDATE DESC
```

... but I'm not sure if the analytic function is allowed in the ORDER BY. If it isn't, calculate it in a subquery and order by in the main query ...

```
select ...
from   (
  select Max(incidentdate) over (partition by vendorname) max_incidentdate_by_vendor,
         ...)
order by max_incidentdate_by_vender desc, incidentdate desc
```

Comment: Ordering by incidentDate second would not necesarilly show all the vendor's incident if there are two vendors with the same latest incident date.

Comment: Yes indeed, bit of an open question on how to deal with that.

Comment: No it's not: `it should come first with all other incident for same vendor and then next Vendor with all respective incident` regards :)

Comment: Actually there are a few issues here. The matter of vendor-ordering for the second+ vendors is not defined in the question. It could be that the vendors are all to be ordered in terms of their most recent incident, or it could be that they order by vendor name following the one with the latest incident. If multiple vendors tie on most recent incident date we could interleave their incidents, or order by vendor name, or tie-break with the second most recent incident date, then the 3rd etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a RAC installation

```
set linesize 300
column REDOLOG_FILE_NAME format a50
SELECT
    a.INST_ID,
    a.GROUP#,
    a.THREAD#,
    a.SEQUENCE#,
    a.ARCHIVED,
    a.STATUS,
    b.MEMBER    AS REDOLOG_FILE_NAME,
    (a.BYTES/1024/1024/1024) AS SIZE_GB
FROM gv$log a
JOIN gv$logfile b ON a.Group#=b.Group# 
AND a.INST_ID=b.INST_ID 
ORDER BY a.INST_ID ASC, a.GROUP# ASC;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select vendorname, incidentid, incidentstatus, incidentdate, max(incidentdate) 
over (partition by vendorname order by incidentdate desc) max_incidentdate
from t1 order by max_incidentdate desc, incidentdate desc
```