# PARTITION BY doesn't work in H2 db

Tags: oracle, h2

I'm using PARTITION BY clause to do sorting on the result. Details for using PARTITION BY is mentioned in this question [Sql Order by on multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897024/sql-order-by-on-multiple-column). It works fine when i run in Oracle. I'm using H2 db for my unit test cases. When i run the same query on H2 db, it doesn't work. Is it known issue in H2? Is there any alternate solution which can work in Oracle and H2 both.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think H2 supports window functions (aka analytic functions).  However, you can do the query in the link using standard SQL:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM yourtable t join
     (select vendorname, max(incidentdate) as maxdate
      from yourtable yt
      group by vendorname
     ) vn
     on vn.vendorname = yt.vendorname
ORDER BY vn.maxDate DESC, t.VendorName ASC, t.IncidentDate DESC;
```

Although this should run in both environments, the `over` form probably performs better in SQL.

Comment: The performance doesn't even compare.  I'm still searching for an in memory database that can be used for testing these queries.

Comment: How large is your database?  The performance shouldn't be *that* bad, unless you have lots and lots of data.

Comment: Very large (150m+ partitions, >1B inserts daily).  This is a big issue that I was hoping would be addressed by now as analytics are ANSI standard.  I'm not going to reduce readability and performance just so I can make functional test easier.  Otherwise it's the tail wagging the dog.  Are any of the embedded databases supporting analytics yet (h2, hsql)?

Comment: @Brian . . . If you have filters on the ultimate query, then you should ask another question with more description about the query, data, and system you are trying to get it to work on.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: My hero.

Comment: Note: This seems to have changed over the years and H2 supports partitioning. source: https://www.h2database.com/html/functions-window.html