# SQL statement working in tool but not in Java using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, h2

I'm using the below SQL query to fetch some data from the database. The DBMS I'm using is H2, a native java implementation. Even though I can retrieve said data using a H2 tool, it gives me the following error when I use it as a `PreparedStatement` in JAVA:

> "; expected ")"; SQL statement: ...

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT temp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY horseid ORDER BY updated desc) as num
   FROM(
   select horseid, name, breed, min_speed, max_speed, updated from horsehistory
   UNION
   select id, name, breed, min_speed, max_speed, updated from horse
   ) as temp
   WHERE updated<? AND horseid in ?
)
WHERE num = 1;
```

I've tried using newlines, stringbuilder with line separator to no avail.

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    appendString(sb, "SELECT * FROM (");
    appendString(sb, "SELECT temp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY horseid ORDER BY updated desc) AS num");
    appendString(sb, "FROM(");
    appendString(sb, "SELECT horseid, name, breed, min_speed, max_speed, updated FROM horsehistory");
    appendString(sb, "UNION");
    appendString(sb, "SELECT id, name, breed, min_speed, max_speed, updated FROM horse");
    appendString(sb, ") AS temp");
    appendString(sb, "WHERE updated < ? AND horseid IN ?");
    appendString(sb, ")");
    appendString(sb, "WHERE num = 1;");
    String sql=sb.toString();
```

The appendString function just appends a newline to the String. I use this in a preparedstatement

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is the full error in question

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT TEMP.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION[*] BY        HORSEID ORDER BY UPDATED DESC) AS NUM FROM ( SELECT HORSEID, NAME, BREED, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED, UPDATED FROM HORSEHISTORY UNION SELECT ID, NAME, BREED, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED, UPDATED FROM HORSE ) AS TEMP WHERE UPDATED < ? AND HORSEID IN (?) ) WHERE NUM = 1  "; expected ")";
```

There is a [*] after PARTITION. Does this mean that the error occurs there?

Comment: What happens when you just remove `;` at the end?

Comment: When you are appending you are excluding spaces. eg. `... AS num"); appendString(sb, "FROM(");` becomes `"AS numFROM("`

Comment: @Lino same error...

Comment: @xtratic the appendString function takes care of it:

`private void appendString(StringBuilder sb, String val){
        sb.append(val + System.lineSeparator());
    }`

Comment: Print your `sql` string and review.

Comment: Which values are you giving for the `?` placeholders ?

Comment: @Arnaud a TimeStamp and an array

Comment: why you're not using String variable here

Comment: sout your query and fire it against your database

Comment: It looks like you tried Linos advice, I'm surprised that wasn't it actually. Now try removing the newlines entirely and see if that fixes anything. use `sb.append(val).append(" ");` instead of `sb.append(val + System.lineSeparator());`

Comment: I tried it that way and also just by copy pasting sql query from tool to string, same error. It seems like the error is somewhere near PARTITION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're using `H2`, thanks for adding that flag. `H2` doesn't seem to support `PARTITION`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930238/2442526)

Comment: this is weird, because it seems to work fine in the h2 console:
https://i.imgur.com/ct0esPM.png

Do you know the reason why it works here?

Comment: @Minimax no idea

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your array-parameter `?` in parentheses:

```
... horseid IN (?) ...
```